# Inaccurate PGF calculation?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fpu

I'm trying to implement an invoice calculation in LaTeX and using PGF as the method to do calculations. I've run into an odd problem where it seems that PGF calculates things incorrectly and I'm not sure what's causing it. Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepgflibrary{fpu}
\pgfkeys{
    /pgf/fpu=true,
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    precision=2,
    fixed,
    fixed zerofill,
    use comma,
    1000 sep={.}
}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathparse{(1*800050)}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}

\end{document}
```

Why does this output 800.050,05 when it should output 800.050,00?

Comment: Section 54.3 of the PGF manual says “The FPU has a uniform relative precision of about 4–5 correct digits”.

Comment: \pgfmathmultiply{1}{80050} gives the right answer.  So the problem is not in the storage or multiplication, it is in \pgfmathparse.

Comment: \pgfmathparse{1*(80050)} also works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you can count on eight exact digits with the `fpu` library; quoting the manual, section 54.3,

> The FPU has a uniform relative precision of about 4–5 correct digits.

You might use the `fp` library of `expl3` and rely on PGF for the number printing:

```
\documentclass[margin=2bp,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \fpeval \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{pgf}
\pgfkeys{
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    precision=2,
    fixed,
    fixed zerofill,
    use comma,
    1000 sep={.}
}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathprintnumber{\fpeval{1*800050}}

\pgfmathprintnumber{\fpeval{800050/4}}

\pgfmathprintnumber{\fpeval{800050/8}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And also, mantissa-exponent representation is not so accurate when the numbers are not relatively close to each other for some reason.

Comment: @percusse You're referring to the FPU library of PGF, aren't you?

Comment: Ah yes I meant `fpu`, sorry.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind compiling with `lualatex` than you can exploit the mathematical capabilities of `lua`:

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,pgffor}
\def\luamath#1{\edef\luamathresult{\directlua{tex.write("" .. #1)}}}
\pgfkeys{
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    precision=2,
    fixed,
    fixed zerofill,
    use comma,
    1000 sep={.}
}
\begin{document}
\parbox{.75in}{
  \foreach \i in {1,...,10}{
    \luamath{800050/\i}\pgfmathprintnumber{\luamathresult}\\
  }
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why the `\edef` here rather than `\def\luamath#1{\directlua{tex.write("" .. #1)}}` and `\pgfmathprintnumber{\luamath{800050/\i}}`?

Comment: @JosephWright no reason specifically, I don't think I thought about it that much. I guess it was just "sort of" analogous to `\pgfmathparse` putting the result of a calculation in `\pgfmathresult`.