# Wrong calculation in Tikz foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I've a misunderstanding about the method Tikz compute some numbers. I draw a graph with some `scale`. Here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=0.1,xscale=25]
    \draw[<->] (0.5,0) node[below right]{t} -- (0,0) -- (0,100) node[above left]{x(t)};

    %%Graduation
    \foreach \t in {0, 0.08, ..., 0.48}{%
        \draw (\t,1) -- (\t,-1) node[below]{\t};}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I thought `0.08 x 5 = 0.40` and not `0.40001`. And why the number 0.48 does not appear ?

I guess the `xscale` factor is not foreign by this problem but i can't address the problem by changing this factor. Otherwise i have a coefficient in all the following graphplots.

I read on this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196171/inaccurate-pgf-calculation) that `pgf` has a uniform relative precision of about 4–5 correct digits. Is it the same for Tikz ? Is there a way to increase the precision of Tikz ?

Thx for you help !

[image: Some wrong numbers appear and the right ones does not.]

Comment: related : [Why does pgffor estimate that 0.1-0=0.100005 in a \foreach loop?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/446008/138900)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The limited precision is the obstacle.

You can get much greater accuracy using `expl3`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\fpforeach}{mmmm}
 {% #1 = start, #2 = step, #3 = end, #4 = what to do
  \fp_step_inline:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=0.1,xscale=25]
\draw[<->] (0.5,0) node[below right]{t} -- (0,0) -- (0,100) node[above left]{x(t)};

%%Graduation
\fpforeach{0}{0.08}{0.48}
 {
  \draw (#1,1) -- (#1,-1) node[below]{#1};
 }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Beware of divisions, though, because the problems are still there and the final step might be missing due to accuracy issues nonetheless, but this is a problem with all floating point computations.

Comment: Is it possible for you to explain what `fp_step_inline:nnnn` do ? I've never seen this command/function and the corresponding syntax untill now.

Comment: @Piroooh It's `expl3`, the programming layer of the future LaTeX3. You can peruse the site finding several examples of how it works.

Answer (score 6):

The Tikz manual states that this is normal, and I quote (p 902):

> Normally, when a list item `...` is encountered, there should already
>   have been two list items before it, which where numbers. Examples of
>   numbers are 1, -10, or -0.24. Let us call these numbers `x` and `y` and
>   let `d := y − x` be their difference. Next, there should also be one
>   number following the three dots, let us call this number `z`.
>
> In this situation, the part of the list reading `x,y,...,z` is replaced by `x, x + d, x + 2d, x + 3d, ..., x + md` where the last dots are semantic
>   dots, not syntactic dots. The value m is the largest number such that
>   `x + md ≤ z` if d is positive or such that `x + md ≥ z` if d is negative.
>
> Perhaps it is best to explain this by some examples: The following
>   `<list>` have the same effects:
>
> `\foreach \x in {1,2,...,6} {\x, } yields 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`
>
> `\foreach \x in {1,2,3,...,6} {\x, } yields 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`
>
> `\foreach \x in {1,3,...,11} {\x, } yields 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11`
>
> `\foreach \x in {1,3,...,10} {\x, } yields 1, 3, 5, 7, 9`
>
> `\foreach \x in {0,0.1,...,0.5} {\x, } yields 0, 0.1, 0.20001, 0.30002, 0.40002`
>
> `\foreach \x in {a,b,9,8,...,1,2,2.125,...,2.5} {\x, } yields a, b, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2.125, 2.25, 2.375, 2.5`

Like you, I asked myself the question and @egreg answered it excellently here: [Why does pgffor estimate that 0.1-0=0.100005 in a \foreach loop?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446051/138900)

Comment: Very nice, in fact it's due to the decimal values and not the `scale` factor !
I read the p.675 in the pgf-tikz manual who is the same than what you have quoted and the answer of @egreg.
A way is simply to erase the dots and to write the numbers one-by-one. Easy for 5 values, less convenient for a bigger sample.
Thx to quote the Tikz manual and the corresponding topic !

Comment: Yes, and  @RuixiZhang gives a way to keep the accuracy of calculations with a `foreach` loop in his answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446027/138900

Answer (score 4):

You can fix this by first working with integers and then *reformatting* the numbers to be the decimal representation you'd like to have:

[image]

First, I set the *precision* for the floating point

```
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/precision=2}
```

Then in the `foreach` loop I parse the integers to become the desired decimals using the following code

```
\pgfmathparse{\t/100}
\pgfmathroundtozerofill{\pgfmathresult}
\pgfmathsetmacro\t{\pgfmathresult}
```

Here's the full code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=0.1,xscale=25]
  \draw[<->] (0.5,0) node[below right]{t} -- (0,0) -- (0,100) node[above left]{x(t)};

  %%Graduation  
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/precision=2}
  \foreach \t in {0, 8, ..., 48}
    {
      \pgfmathparse{\t/100}
      \pgfmathroundtozerofill{\pgfmathresult}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\t{\pgfmathresult}
      \draw (\t,1) -- (\t,-1) 
             node[below]
            {\t};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: By this way, there is no risk Tikz make also rounded errors ? By divinding in `pgfmathparse{\t/100}` ? Or it is the goal to use `\pgfmathroundtozerofill` ?
I'm not familiar with `pgf`.

Comment: It's not that TikZ makes a rounding error so much as TeX underlying mechanism for doing arithmetic allows errors to gradually creep in if you're working with non-integer values (this will be true for any computer system).  `pgf` is what underlies TikZ.  The *round to zero fill* works with the designated *precision* to represent the decimal number with exactly two digits.